# NSInternalInconsistencyException: webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler was not called

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I'm trying to disable link loading inside a wkWebView, so I'm using decidePolicyForNavigationAction for this, but my app gives me this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'
>   reason: 'Completion handler passed to -[ViewController webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:] was not called'

This is the simplified code that gives me this error:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: config)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.insertSubview(webView, atIndex: 1)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: -44)
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([height, width])


        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:"https://www.apple.com")!))


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {

        if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.LinkActivated){
            print(navigationAction.request.URL?.relativeString)
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but it looks like you **must** call decisionHandler, no matter what your decision is. Try adding `else { decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow) }` to the end of your delegate method.

Answer (score 36):

You have to call the `decisionHanler` for each case.

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
    if (navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated){
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's Day saver!

Answer (score 7):

it means that if you call `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` ,you can only call `decisionHandler(XX)` **at once a time.** 
Otherwise the app will crash may occur about `NSInternalInconsistencyException: webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler was not called`

(1)swift

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
    if (custom condition){
        decisionHandler(XX) //  if... return as well
    } else {
        decisionHandler(XX)
    }
}
```

(2) OC

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

    NSString *url = [navigationAction.request.URL absoluteString];
    url = [url stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([url rangeOfString:@"xxxx://"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // custom fundation
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
         return; // the same as to use if...else 
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fully Tested in Swift 5 or above**

> here is a complete example. if you have any confusion please comment below. I was also facing some problems but I just improve the little condition and decisionHandler().

```
    extension WebViewVC: WKNavigationDelegate {
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            
            print("Start loading")
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.loader.hideLoader()
            print("End loading")
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            switch navigationAction.navigationType {
            case .linkActivated:
                if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
                    self.webView?.load(navigationAction.request)// It will load that link in same WKWebView
                 
                }
            default:
                break
            
            }
            
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url , url != self.urlString?.toURL {
                debugPrint(url.absoluteString) // It will give the selected link URL
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
                
            }
            else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
            
        }

}
```