# Swift: Crash in libMainThreadChecker while loading WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am using `Xcode 13.1`.

Following Crash occurred in `WKWebView`!

```
NSException *   "Completion handler passed to -[WebViewController webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:] was not called


dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/
introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer
/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks
/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

I have searched related to this! But results were related to add/remove external frameworks.

Here I have not used any frameworks here. Kindly guide me how to solve this?

Comment: You have a `WebViewController`?  You implemented `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)`? Show the code for that method. You need to call `decisionHander(someValue)` at the end of the method, in each if/else case you have.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667626/thread-1-signal-sigabrt-from-web-view-when-accessing-external-link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307430/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-webviewdecidepolicyfornavigationactiondecisi etc.

Comment: Thanks @Larme . Finally crash resolved !

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed decisionHandler(value)